# Como llenar un JComboBox en Java con base de datos en SQL Server?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que ocupo llenar un combobox con una lista de países, sin embargo solo me muestra garabatos, el código lo tengo asi:

**Capa de negocio**

```
public ArrayList<ciudadDAO> listar() {
    ArrayList<ciudadDAO> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        st = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Ciudades WHERE Activo = 1 ORDER BY Descripcion");
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            ciudadDAO obj = new ciudadDAO();
            obj.setId(rs.getInt("Id_Ciudad"));
            obj.setNombre(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
            lista.add(obj);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        Conexion.cerrarPrep(st);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

**Vista**

Aquí es donde trato de cargar el dato para que me muestre la lista de ciudades.

```
private void listarCiudades()
{
    ArrayList<ciudadDAO> ciudades = ciudad.listar();
    DefaultComboBoxModel comboC = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    
    if(!ciudades.isEmpty())
    {
        for(ciudadDAO ciudad : ciudades)
        {
            Object[] fila = {
                ciudad.getNombre()
            };
            comboC.addElement(fila);
            jcb_Ciudad.setModel(comboC);
        }
    }
}
```

Y con este código solo obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
private void listarCiudades()
{
    jcb_Ciudad.removeAllItems();
    
    ArrayList<ciudadDAO> ciudades = ciudad.listar();
    
    if(!ciudades.isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ciudades.size(); i++)
        {
            jcb_Ciudad.addItem(ciudades.get(i).getNombre());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de agregar un objeto a tu `DefaultComboBoxModel`  (este es el problema), define el nombre de la ciudad:

```
 ...
 ...
  for(ciudadDAO ciudad : ciudades)
     {
        /*Object[] fila = {
            ciudad.getNombre()
        };
        comboC.addElement(fila);*/

        comboC.addElement(ciudad.getNombre()); //*Agrega nombre de ciudad.
        jcb_Ciudad.setModel(comboC);
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: No me funciono men

Answer (score 1):

Si a CiudadDAO le pones un método toString() sobreescribiendo al de la clase Object, este será el que use JComboBox para mostrar. De esta forma podrías meter en JComboBox el objeto CiudadDAO completo, se mostraría correctamente y cuando preguntes al JComboBox por el getSelectedItem(), tendrás CiudadDAO completo y no solo el nombre.

Ya es cuestión de ver que opción te viene mejor, si meter sólo el nombre o meter CiudadDAO completo.